# C++ Wierd crash on function called

Tags: c++, mysql, world-of-warcraft

I checked the return of `GetCharacterRankINT()` and it is returning the right value (1). When I tested the query with the rankNum 1 I got the right result, but whenever I try to use `GetCharacterRankSTR()` it crashes with the following crash dump: http://fbe.am/rwl (Password: stackoverflow). I tried to set the type of the function from string to std::string and it still didn't work. The MySQL table has **8** columns, or so the field has 8 entries. Therefore the error is not related to the amount of fields.

```
string Player::GetCharacterRankSTR()
{
    QueryResult* res = CharacterDatabase.Query("SELECT * FROM ars_ranks WHERE rankNum = %u LIMIT 1;", GetCharacterRankINT());
    if (!res)
    {
        return "Error";
    }
    else
    {
        Field* fld = res->Fetch();
        return fld[3].GetString();
    }
}
```

My question is: What am I doing wrong in the function so that it crashes?

Comment: Have you checked the size of fld? what if it is less than 3?

Comment: In the mysql table I made sure that the size of the field is less than 3.

Comment: Errors belong here in the post, not in some password-protected file on some random site.

Comment: You mean you made sure it is larger than 3, not less than, right?

Comment: It is password-protected??? And yes it is greater than 3, not less than 3.

Comment: At least four fields must be in the result you get back, as `fld[3]` accesses the *fourth* entry.

Comment: The table has **8** columns, or so the field has 8 entries and none of the fields are empty.

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger? It will stop at the location of the crash, and also let you examine the call-stack and values of variables. At least it will narrow it down to the exact line where the crash happens, which might help.

Comment: Running it right now.

Comment: No suck luck with the debugger... seems like it cannot be ran.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, I found out how to fix it... I just had to change from string to const char *.

Comment: That... doesn't make any sense! A string object should be able to be created from a `const char *`, if that's what the `GetString()` function returns.

Comment: @JoachimPuleborg I completely agree with you, but nothing makes sense in the world of warcraft emulation.